# Versatility and validity of aggregate algorithm for a multiple criteria decision problem (averaging)

Tags: mean, data-transformation, normalization, quantiles, z-score

I'm trying to aggregate different variables in multiple scales and distributions. The distributions are not known beforehand, but I want to generate a general statistical value that represents all the variables combined for each datapoint.

This is to find the optimal option, knowing that each measure has the same weight.

My first approach to this is to apply a yeo-johnson transformation, followed by a Z-score transformation, and finally using some kind of average, maybe simply an arithmetic average.

I thought about using percentiles but I'm afraid of losing precision and that the aggregation value won't be valid

Is this approach correct?

Comment: possibly, although your method is more complex than the average index composition. what would be acceptable or even good depends on your field and your goal.

Comment: A better question might be: "What way of aggregating is most helpful for reaching some goal?" And this may be susceptible to statistical analysis. But there is no general standard of validity of an aggregation.